# Add ListView right click copy menu

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

So i have this Dictionary:

```
 Dictionary<string, double> _statistics;
```

And this is how this is looks like:

[image]

When I do a mouse right click I want to be able to copy the cell value.
How can I add this simple copy option that will mark only the specific cell and not all the row ?
Is there something that already exist in the `ListView` ?

Populate my `ListView`:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> item in _statistics)
    listView.Items.Add(new MyItem { IP = item.Key, Percent = item.Value });

<ListView.View>
    <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderStyle}">
        <!-- ip address column -->
        <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="IP Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IP}" />

        <!-- percent column sent -->
        <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Percent" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Percent, StringFormat={}{0}%}"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>

public class MyItem
{
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public double Percent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How is this connected to ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridViewColumn.CellTemplate` is the key. Define custom data template for your cell using `CellTemplate` of the `GridViewColumn`, and create a `ContextMenu` in there.

Comment: @markyer sure, [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101360/textblock-text-wrapping-in-gridviewcolumn-celltemplate-not-working) contains an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can catch the mouse click event at the list view level, and check the source element is a `TextBlock`. If so, set the clipboard text to the text block's value.