# Expand columns vertically when adding content in a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, visual-studio-2015

I'm creating a windows WPF interface for an XML API of a Music catalog.

So in creating the list of albums, songs, playlists, etc, I created list boxes with columns (with visual studio 'cause I have no experience on windows programming):

```
<Window x:Class="AmpacheWPF.Programacion"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AmpacheWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Programacion" Height="917.833" Width="1206.666">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
    <ListView x:Name="albums" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="146" Margin="26,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="549" SelectionChanged="albums_SelectionChanged">

        <ListView.View >
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu/>
                </GridView.ColumnHeaderContextMenu>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Album"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Album}" Width="120"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Artist"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Year"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ListView x:Name="Songs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="257" Margin="26,286,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="549" SelectionChanged="Songs_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="#"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Pista}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Cancion"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Titulo}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Compositor"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Compositor}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Artista"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Tiempo"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Tiempo}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Genero"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Genero}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

It has Columns (Album, Artist, Year)
All the info is auto-filled with the XML API of my music server.

I have a combo box with Genres (Latin, Salsa, etc)

Every time I click a genre it loads the info in the ListView albums, and when I click an album it fills the ListView songs.

What I'm trying to do with no success is to fix the columns' size (that is the only thing I can do with "width") and want the columns to expand vertically when the text doesn't fit on the column width (like Microsoft excel does) (so I have a 2 or 3 line rows) but please tell me where to put it on the code because really I have no experience programming on windows.

Here is some example of my code in case it helps:

```
public Programacion()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serverurl = Loginwindow.serverurl;
        string ampuser = Loginwindow.ampuser;
        token = Loginwindow.token;

        //obteniendo lista de tags
        string tagurl = "http://" + serverurl + "/server/xml.server.php?action=tags&auth=" + token;
        string[] tagarray = { tagurl, "1", "tag", "name", "albums" };//Creando array con datos a utilizar
        tagsinfo = xmlcs2.Xmlparser(tagarray);//Llamando afuncion que lee XML

        //Obteniendo total de espacios musicales contando el array
        totalgenres = tagsinfo.GetUpperBound(0);

        //Lennado ComboBox1
        int g = Programacion.totalgenres;
        for (int y = 0; y < g; y++)
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add(tagsinfo[y][1]); //
        }

    }

    private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = comboBox.SelectedIndex;
        id = tagsinfo[index][0];
        string totalalbums = tagsinfo[index][2];


        //obteniendo lista de albums
        string tagurl = "http://" + serverurl + "/server/xml.server.php?action=tag_albums&auth=" + token + "&filter=" + id;
        string[] tagarray = { tagurl, totalalbums, "album", "name", "tracks", "artist", "year" };//Creando array con datos a utilizar
        albumsinfo = xmlcs2.Xmlparser(tagarray);//Llamando afuncion que lee XML

        //ordenando alfabeticamente
        Sort(albumsinfo, 1);

        //Lennado ListView Albums
        albums.ItemsSource = null;
        int g = Convert.ToInt32(totalalbums);

        List<Albumlist> items = new List<Albumlist>();
        for (int y = 0; y < g; y++)
        {

            if (albumsinfo[y][4] == "0")
            {

                items.Add(new Albumlist() { Album = albumsinfo[y][1], Artist = albumsinfo[y][3], Year = "" });


            }
            else
            {
                items.Add(new Albumlist() { Album = albumsinfo[y][1], Artist = albumsinfo[y][3], Year = albumsinfo[y][4], Id = albumsinfo[y][0] });



            }



        }
        albums.ItemsSource = items;


    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextBlock text wrapping in GridViewColumn.CellTemplate not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101360/textblock-text-wrapping-in-gridviewcolumn-celltemplate-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you need to do is change out the DisplayMemberBinding in your GridView for CellTemplate as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101360/textblock-text-wrapping-in-gridviewcolumn-celltemplate-not-working), which will allow you to customize the presenter object into a custom TextBlock with wrapping (this will then also do the right thing with regards to letting the grid layout know it needs more space).

You might not get Excel-behavior right away, and you may need to play around with the other TextBlock settings to get it to work exactly how you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, ihave seen that post but with your explanation now im understand what should I change, i will post the finall code for someone who needs it on the future